# Best Book or Source for learning Multivariable Calculus!

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request

I urgently need some sources for learning multivariable calculus in an efficient way, without too much intuition.

I'd like it to be explained in a clear and concise way and with a number of worked examples, I am yet to find a good source.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Ok.  I have retracted above vote.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend this: [Multivariable Calculus, 7th Edition by James Stewart](http://www.cengagebrain.com/shop/en/US/storefront/US;CMGTJSESSIONID=qGCVTTVPJTg3ZPmY5BM8J1V4K8JQ6j8X6N8jWB1TCv6T2D5RPCHF!-46321300?cmd=catProductDetail&gclid=CjgKEAjw8MqcBRCsv5Kf8NCUwlgSJADL4ihh9CpHoqeebIoucREi20lL2-W5rCc5dUXs7Rs0FqC81PD_BwE&entryPoint=storefront&cid=GSEM1&ISBN=9780538497879&messageType=catProductDetail)

I have read it before and it is just so through in every lesson explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try the book "Functions of Several Real Variables" by Moskowitz and Paliogiannis.